# Программы для верстки!

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, html5, вёрстка

Я увлекся веб версткой сайтов из psd шаблонов.Хочу спросить какие приложения помогут мне в этом.Пока у меня есть atom[с кучей плагинов] , avocode , gimp , opera[для просмотра результата].

Comment: Виндового Блокнота вполне достаточно для всего

Comment: Я тоже атомом пользовался но на brackets перешел и вполне доволен.

Comment: Может новость , но виндовский блокнот не открывает psd файлы , как и картинки вобщем

Comment: Так же рекомендую обратить внимание на плагин для браузера "PerfectPixel"

Comment: Я надеялся, что расписывать очевидные вещи не понадобится. Тогда так: виндового блокнота, фотошопа, браузера и компьютера с дисплеем и каким-нибудь устройством ввода, а также питающего всё это дело электричества вполне достаточно для всего

Comment: Зачем писать в блокноте если есть редакторы ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Когда блокнот перестал быть редактором?)

Comment: Ок. Зачем писать в блокноте если есть умные редакторы-,-.

Comment: Простите конечно что написал так мало инфы. Но вы пишите совершенно очевидные и интуитивно понятные вещи. Мне нужны десктоп приложения для [професиональной] верстки. Как фотошоп , зеплин или тот же самый авокод.

Comment: А приведенного вами набора недостаточно?

Comment: Чем вам для профессиональной вёрстки не угодил блокнот? Опишите чёткие требования к ожидаемой вами программе, иначе вопрос будет закрыт как необъективный

Comment: Maybe something like

Comment: Ну не знаю по моему спорить о блокноте - бред. Как сказал один пользователь на тостере: "Объект объективно функциональнее функции".

Comment: 1)Для открытия psd - Какой-то ваше приложение 2)Для редактирования кода - еще что-то и тд

Comment: Для открытия psd есть фотошоп. С редактированием кода прекрасно справляется виндовый блокнот. Видимо, на этом вопрос можно закрывать :)

Comment: @andreymal даже блокнот не нужен. Chrome может подключаться к файловой системе, и все правки в браузере сразу летят в локальный файл)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - лучшая альтернатива для Atom
- $ [Dreamweaver](https://www.adobe.com/ru/products/dreamweaver.html) - редактор от Adobe, с возможностью визуальной компоновки, может открывать/импортировать PSD
- [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) - от Adobe, (может открывать/импортировать PSD, но по моему сейчас поддержка этой опции прекращена)
- $ [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) - "самый лучший" редактор для веб-разработчика

Альтернативы Chrome/Opera при разработке есть, например [Firefox  Quantum](https://www.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/developer/). Но думаю пока Chrome самый подходящий.

Для обучения хорошо походят сервисы типа [CodePen](https://codepen.io/).

VsCode/Atom, Chrome - вполне достаточно для работы.

Comment: Спасибо.Кстати brackets я пользуюсь давно и Extract(импортирование psd шаблонов и извлечение из них данных) просто переименовали.Все же спасибо.Закрывайте вопрос

Comment: [user303393](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303393/user303393), если ответ подходит, отметьте его как решение, сами

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 3 - Редактор
И еще скачай несколько браузеров, чтобы делать кроссбраузерную верстку